# C++: how to get the type of a variable and use this as a template

Tags: c++, templates, types

I'm wriging a wrapper for C++ of a function declared in this way:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  template <class T>
  T& as();
};
```

My wrapper needs to eliminate the explicit template because I don't want to call `myClass.as<int>();`

So I tried to implement a new function declared in this way:

```
class MyClass2 : public MyClass
{
public:
  template <class T>
  void get(T & val);
};
```

In this way I can call

```
int a;
myClass2.get(a);
```

Is there a way to implement this function, so the type is passed at runtime according to the parameter type? Something like:

```
template <class T>
void MyClass2::get(T & val)
{
  val = as< typeof(val) >();  /* Of course typeof does not exist */
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: It sounds a little bit like you want to make a template type at run time? Which as far as I know, you can't do that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This does not make sense. Why not just write:

```
template <class T>
void MyClass2::get(T & val)
{
  val = as< T >();
}
```

Since the type is a template-parameter, you need no `typeof`.

Answer (score 6):

As @Space_C0wb0y already pointed out, this isn't actually necessary. The template type is automatically inferred from the parameter.

However, C++0x *does* actually add what you asked for, in that it would let you write:

```
template <class T>
void MyClass2::get(T & val)
{
  val = as< decltype(val) >();  /* typeof does not exist. But decltype does */
}
```

of course, in this case it's just a more complex way to solve a non-existent problem. But I thought I'd demonstrate it anyway, because it is so similar to the pseudocode you posted in the question.